# c++ DLL runtime error "abc.dll is not a valid WIN32 application".Please help to solve this

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I am using Visual Studio 2015. i have created a DLL WIN32 application where there are  .h and .cpp files. when i build the project, the build is successful . A dll is created in the project path . but there is a run time error saying ".dll is not a valid WIN32 application"

Answer (score 0):

Only  *.exe can run so add another win32 app project to your solution.
Mark it as startup project then choose from project dependency the dll project so when build the output dll and lib will be linked correctly.